# How to used count in append text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m using to multiple add text with a button as like form, and I want to use the count for change input id or name but this is not reflected in my code.

If I used to this count in simple than it's, working but if I used to in string than it's not working. Please tell me where I'm wrong in my code.

```js
$('#singleTextbtn').on('click', function() {
  singleLineText();
  console.log(count);
  return false;
});
var count = 0;

function singleLineText() {
  count++;
  var slt = count + "count+<li><div class='formSection'+count> <label for='singleLineText_'+count>Single Line Text </label><input type='text' value='' name='singleLineText_'+count id='singleLineText_'+count /><div class='actionSec'> <span class='addBtn' title='click here to add more'></span><span class='removeBtn' title='click here to remove'></span></div> </div> </li>";
  $('#rohit').append(slt);

};
```

```css
#singleTextbtn {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="singleTextbtn">click to add </a>

<ul id="rohit"></ul>
```

Comment: Easy, Use proper quotes. `var slt = count + " count + <li><div class='formSection'+" + count + "> <label for='singleLineText_'+" + count + ">Single Line Text </label><input type='text' value='' name='singleLineText_'+" + count + " id='singleLineText_'+" + count + " /><div class='actionSec'> <span class='addBtn' title='click here to add more'></span><span class='removeBtn' title='click here to remove'></span></div> </div> </li>";`

Comment: You are appending variable in double inverted string.
try this,
Eg: var temp = "your-text"+count;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: You were using count as an string. just added proper concatenation for count variable.

```
    $('#singleTextbtn').on('click', function() {
  singleLineText();
  console.log(count);
  return false;
});
var count = 0;

function singleLineText() {
  count++;
  var slt = count + "<li><div class='formSection_"+count+"'> <label for='singleLineText_"+count+"'>Single Line Text </label><input type='text' value='' name='singleLineText_"+count+"' id='singleLineText_"+count+"' /><div class='actionSec'> <span class='addBtn' title='click here to add more'></span><span class='removeBtn' title='click here to remove'></span></div> </div> </li>";
  $('#rohit').append(slt);

};
```

===========================

```js
$('#singleTextbtn').on('click', function() {
  singleLineText();
  console.log(count);
  return false;
});
var count = 0;

function singleLineText() {
  count++;
  var slt = count + "<li><div class='formSection_"+count+"'> <label for='singleLineText_"+count+"'>Single Line Text </label><input type='text' value='' name='singleLineText_"+count+"' id='singleLineText_"+count+"' /><div class='actionSec'> <span class='addBtn' title='click here to add more'></span><span class='removeBtn' title='click here to remove'></span></div> </div> </li>";
  $('#rohit').append(slt);

};
```

```css
#singleTextbtn {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="singleTextbtn">click to add </a>


<ul id="rohit"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your code but you have to edit this line only..

```
var slt =count+"count+<li><div class='formSection"+count+"'> <label for='singleLineText_"+count+"'>Single Line Text </label><input type='text' value='' name='singleLineText_"+count+"'  id='singleLineText_"+count+"' /><div class='actionSec'> <span class='addBtn' title='click here to add more'></span><span class='removeBtn' title='click here to remove'></span></div> </div> </li>";
```

Good Luck ['}

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got you...

I think you escaped your "count" wrong:

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gLtdd3u1/) is a working fiddle.

Basically you have to escape the "count" in all of your class names and so on:

e.g. `<div class='formSection"+count+"'>`

Answer (score 1):

You should close the string and append it with + sign like this:

```
function singleLineText() {
      count++;
      var slt = count + "count+<li><div class='formSection'"+count+"> <label for='singleLineText_'"+count+">Single Line Text </label><input type='text' value='' name='singleLineText_'"+count+" id='singleLineText_'"+count+" /><div class='actionSec'> <span class='addBtn' title='click here to add more'></span><span class='removeBtn' title='click here to remove'></span></div> </div> </li>";
      $('#rohit').append(slt);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your string is properly formated.
To use a variable in your string you have 2 options.

```
var myString = "count: "+count+" using double quotes"

var myString2 = 'count: '+count+' using single quotes'
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the html as follows.

```
 var slt = count + "count+<li><div class='formSection'+count> <label for='singleLineText_'+count>Single Line Text </label><input type='text' value='' name='singleLineText_"+count+"  id='singleLineText_"+count+"  /><div class='actionSec'> <span class='addBtn' title='click here to add more'></span><span class='removeBtn' title='click here to remove'></span></div> </div> </li>";
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/89bMEa5G3Jq9p1IQhM1X?p=preview)